# Include JS functions

Tags: javascript, php, html, include

In the project that i working in, there is a PHP file that have some JS functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function alertaProximaBloqueada(){
    [...]
  }
  function ManualAluno() {
    [...]
  }
  [...]
</script>
```

This file is included at the end of the view that uses these functions, like this:

```
</body>
<?php include 'Includes/funcoes_ameai.php';?>
```

Quando olho no código fonte com o crtl+u as funções estão todas lá, mas quando tento executar qualquer uma, recebo esse erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: NOME_DA_FUNCAO is not defined
>   [...]

The weirdest thing is that if I copy the function and paste in the same place it is being included, inside the view (between the  tags), I can execute it normally.

Comment: weird you are including it after the body tag.

Comment: @epascarello 
when I started working the system was already finished ... and it was working

Comment: Yes js scripts need to be inside `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: @NikkoKhresna i will try this

Comment: @NikkoKhresna still the same

Comment: weird...where do you assign value for `NOME_DA_FUNCAO` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the script inside the head of html.

Besides use brackets:

`include('Includes/funcoes_ameai.php');`

Answer (score 0):

put your include statement inside your **head** section

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'Includes/funcoes_ameai.php';?>
<title>do not forget to give a title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```